# How to populate an array of objects dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js

```js
let products = [
  {
    name: "a",
    inventory: 1
  },
  {
    name: "b",
    inventory: 2
  },
  {
    name: "c",
    inventory: 3
  }
];
```

How can I go about creating these objects in an array like this dynamically ?
Here is what I have been trying to do.

```js
choicesHolder = [{name: '', inventory: ''}];

for(i; element.length<0; i--) {
    choicesHolder.push({"name": element.value, "inventory": element.selected});
}
```

**element** holds the data from the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the map method.

[MDN docs about map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
const choicesHolder = arrayOfElement.map(element => {
  return {
    name: element.value,
    inventory: element.selected
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let res = [];
let char = 'a'
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    res.push({ "name": char, "inventory": i + 1 });
    char = String.fromCharCode(char.charCodeAt(0) + 1) // 'B'
}
console.log(res)
```